# Lubuntu and remote desktop

Tags: ssh, vnc

I have a SSH address that I connect through command line, but I would like to have a GUI option to make my work easier. So is it possible to connect through ssh using remote desktop on Lubuntu 11.10? Thanks

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault or Ask Ubuntu, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for:

https://wiki.edubuntu.org/Lubuntu/RemoteDesktop

Comment: yeah but it says "Allowing fully graphical remote access to your Lubuntu machine can be useful." I want to connect to another machine not mine

Comment: What operating system is the other machine running?

Comment: it is running redhat, but I have no admin access to it

Comment: You can start an X session once you are SSH'd in, otherwise I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

x11vnc server for use with Lubuntu. Download via Synaptic.

It can be run for single use from a terminal:-

```
x11vnc -display :0
```

It is more useful when run like:

```
x11vnc -forever -display :0
```

...so you can connect/disconnect/reconnect when needed.

I run it from a simple script that auto runs on startup. Create a new file called "startvnc.sh" and add this:-

```
 #!/bin/sh   x11vnc -forever -display :0
```

...then put it in /usr/bin (which is in the $PATH) and make it executable.

Then to autostart, in terminal:-

```
 sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

...and add this at the end of this file:-
  @startvnc.sh
You should be able to connect via almost any remote vnc client like this: {IP}::{port}
e.g. 192.168.0.7::5902

Comment: I am doing this with Luubuntu to access on Mac OSX by chicken VNC and VNC viewer, works perfectly